# Simplemodal - iframe won't close

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal from http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/.

The problem I'm having is that I can't close the iframe once it's open.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Route Which Page

$.modal('<iframe src="<?= $src ?>" height="230" width="550" style="border:0">', {
    closeHTML:"<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#eee",
        borderColor:"#ddd",
        height:230,
        padding:0,
        width:550
    },
    overlayClose:false
});

    /* When #btnClose is clicked, close the modal */    
    $('#disagree').on("click", function(event){
        parent.$.modal.close();
    });

</script>
```

Pops up and work great, just can't get the popup to close! I have used all google's ideas just wont close. I can get it to close, which it flickers then opens a second iframe under.

I've used the following code to close:

```
/* When #btnClose is clicked, close the modal */    
$('#disagree').on("click", function(event){
    $.modal.close();
});


/* When #btnClose is clicked, close the modal */    
$('#disagree').on("click", function(event){
    parent.$.modal.close();
});

<a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close simplemodal-close">x</a>
```

The actual modal settings:

```
closeHTML:"<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
```

Works fine, but I need action buttons to close which are inside of the iframe which is being loaded.

Any ideas or help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Add event to your link in iframe

```
$('.modal-close').click( function() {
        parent.$.modal.close();
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me, this code is placed in the iframe page.  No other calls to the js is needed.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the simple demo that pops up and then looking at the click event data used on the close link I've found this:

> function (b){b.preventDefault();a.close()}

That data is from the close ahref `<a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close" id="modalId"></a>` from this link [Basic Modal Dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)

Can you not then try this:

```
 $('#disagree').on("click", function(event)
   {
     $('#modalId').trigger('click');
     //OR:
     $('.modalCloseImg').trigger('click');
   });
```

"modalId" is just an Id I gave to that above ahref link. Alternatively you can do: `$('#IdOfiFrame').remove();`